# How do I generate a custom message from a custom Mockito ArgumentMatcher?

Tags: mocking, mockito

I'm writing an ArgumentMatcher and the guts of the comparison come down to something like:

```
return A.value().equals(B.value()) && A.name().equals(B.name());
```

Unfortunately, when the doesn't pass, Mockito just tells me it failed. I want to add a custom message like "Values don't match" or "Names don't match" (of course I'd like to give more info, but until I can figure out this simple case, what's the point of going any further).

Previously (before working with Mockito), I remember matchers having two methods - one to check the match and one to generate a failure message (true, it was a pain to write both methods, but I miss the second method now).

Any idea how to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it now. Hamcrest provides a "describeTo" method. This is equivalent to the method I remember from EasyMock. You simply add your error conditions to the Description object, and viola, you have a better failure message.

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thank you! May you multiply :)

Answer (score 3):

A general way of providing custom messages is through [`Mockito.description()`](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#description(java.lang.String)) method:

```
verify(writer, never().description("exception was thrown"))
  .println(any(Object.class));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are implementing the `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher` interface, the test will call its `toString()` method to create the "Wanted" side of the comparison message. Implementing this method by simply returning the value of the `toString()` method on the expected object used to initialize the `ArgumentMatcher` will likely get you a useful message.

Answer (score 2):

I am warping junit assert into argThat

```java
        verify(mockBuildingRepo, times(1))
                .save(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Building>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Building building) {
                        assertEquals("Test upload response", building.getName());
                        return true;
                    }
                }));
```

It will give me meaningful message like

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :Test upload resp2onse
Actual   :Test upload response
<Click to see difference>
```